# Adding new CVs to a Storage

Tags: openpathsampling, plumed

I am trying to add a new CV (A plumed one) to a storage. I've completed a TPS simulation, and now I want to store the new CV for later analysis use.

```
import openpathsampling as paths
storage = paths.Storage("TPS_eq.nc")
...
plmd = PLUMEDInterface(ops_topology,logfile=os.devnull)
plmd.set('','UNITS LENGTH=A')
...
CV_dihed_Op2Op3Op4P=PLUMEDCV("CV_dihed_o1o2o3o4",plmd,"TORSION ATOMS=o1,o2,o3,o4")

storage.save(CV_dihed_o1o2o3o4)
storage.cvs.add_diskcache(CV_dihed_o1o2o3o4, allow_incomplete=True)

all_snapshots = storage.snapshots.all()

storage.cvs["CV_dihed_o1o2o3o4"](all_snapshots)
storage.cvs.sync(storage.cvs["CV_dihed_o1o2o3o4"])
storage.close()
```

If I reload the storage, the CV will be present (as in storage.cvs), but the values will be 'recomputed' and not saved to the storage.
ndeed, the storage.cvXX files are empty (store.cvXX[None/ANY]: 0 object(s)) compared to the data stored during the simulation in store.cv0[None/ANY]: 8224 object(s). The same applies to the storage.vars, where storage.vars["cv36_index"] and its corresponding values are currently empty (shape = (0,)).

Am I missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: Please spell out all acronyms and use `code` blocks for code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add your TPS_eq.nc file as a code block

Comment: It's a 2G files. My only hope is for a user or developer of OPS to see this.

Comment: Once an answer has been written, please stop changing the question. If you have new questions, you can ask them in new posts.

Comment: I would agree with Nike, the Q&A model of the site isn't set up well to handle having those sort of continuations in one post, rather than new separate questions.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, this gets into a few corners of OpenPathSampling (OPS) where I'm not terribly familiar with the underlying code. From playing around a bit, I suspect that part of the confusion might be that the `allow_incomplete` parameter isn't doing what I would expect it to do (possibly a bug, but I didn't write that code, and it isn't well-documented what the intended use was).

That said, I don't think you want `allow_incomplete=True`, anyway. If you want to calculate this collective variable (CV) for all snapshots, then you want to have the complete list of values for snapshots in your storage. Below is something that seems to work for me (caveat that I'm using an MDTraj CV, not a PLUMED CV, but that shouldn't make a difference). One thing that might make a difference: versions of `netcdf4` (mine is 1.6.0) and `libnetcdf` (mine is 4.8.1).

The main differences with your approach are that, instead of working with the `storage.cvs` object, I enable disk caching on my CV itself, and I calculate the CV before saving things. Then I let the default `Storage.save` method do the rest of the work for me. This is similar to what happens under the hood when you do a transition path sampling (TPS) step: after the TPS step, the whole `MCStep` object is sent to `save`. Any new information is extracted and saved.

If I understand, the story here is "I ran some TPS, and decided later that there was a second CV that would be interesting to analyze as well." This is a very common use case. I'll try to simulate that with two scripts: the two scripts are very similar, but the first gets its data from a trajectory that hasn't been saved by OPS yet, whereas the second loops over all snapshots in an OPS storage file.

```py
# assumes you have OpenPathSampling, MDTraj, and OpenMM installed
import openpathsampling as paths
import mdtraj as md

# let's load up a tiny trajectory that is in the OPS test suite
from openpathsampling.tests.test_helpers import data_filename
from openpathsampling.engines.openmm.tools import ops_load_trajectory
traj = ops_load_trajectory(data_filename("ala_small_traj.pdb"))

# create a CV and enable disk caching on it
cv = paths.MDTrajFunctionCV("phi", md.compute_dihedrals, traj[0].topology, indices=[[4, 6, 8, 14]])
cv.enable_diskcache()  # defaults to allow_incomplete=False

st1 = paths.Storage("foo.nc", mode='w')
cv(traj)

# save the trajectory and the CV itself
st1.save(traj)
st1.save(cv)
st1.sync()
```

Then we see that this variable has 10 entries (current shape, one for each snapshot) in the NetCDF file:

```
st1.vars['cv0_value']
# <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
# float32 cv0_value(snapshots)
#     var_type: numpy.float32
# unlimited dimensions: snapshots
# current shape = (10,)
# filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used
```

Now let's do the second stage. (If you're playing along at home in a single process [notebook], you'll need to do `st1.close()` before the next part.) Overall, this is very similar, but now we'll loop over all the snapshots in the storage file.

```py
import openpathsampling as paths
import mdtraj as md

st2 = paths.Storage("foo.nc")

st2.snapshots
# store.snapshots[BaseSnapshot] : 20 object(s)
# 20 because there are "ghost" snapshots representing velocity-reversed versions

[cv.name for cv in st2.cvs]
# ['phi']

top = st2.snapshots[0].topology
cv1 = paths.MDTrajFunctionCV("psi", md.compute_dihedrals, top, indices=[[6, 8, 14, 16]])
cv1.enable_diskcache()

cv1(st2.snapshots)

st2.save(cv1)
st2.sync()
```

And then we'll have a `cv1_value` in addition to our `cv0_value`:

```py
st2.vars['cv1_value']
# <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
# float32 cv1_value(snapshots)
#     var_type: numpy.float32
# unlimited dimensions: snapshots
# current shape = (10,)
# filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used
```

[NB: all of this is based on the `netcdfplus` storage subsystem. OPS is migrating to a different storage subsystem, `simstore`, in the future, precisely because of some of the challenges in maintaining `netcdfplus`.]

---

**UPDATE:** From comments and updates to the question, it is clear that this use case requires only storing CV results for *some* snapshots in a single run (useful if, e.g., the CV is very expensive to calculate). The solution above works if you're doing all snapshots at once; update below gives a way to only fill in some.

NB: This is all a bit experimental. This, or something very close to it should work, but I'd recommend storing an unedited copy of your nc file before doing this; just in case. The following assumes you've run the code blocks with `st1` above.

##### Preparation, once per CV you want to add

In this, we will create and save the CV, without applying it to any snapshots.

```py
import openpathsampling as paths
import mdtraj as md

st2 = paths.Storage("foo.nc")
[cv.name for cv in st2.cvs]  # so far we only have the phi CV
# ['phi']

# create and save the other CV (psi)
top = st2.snapshots[0].topology
cv1 = paths.MDTrajFunctionCV("psi", md.compute_dihedrals, top, indices=[[6, 8, 14, 16]])
cv1.with_diskcache(allow_incomplete=True)
st2.save(cv1)

st2.close()
```

##### Main script: run for each slice of snapshots

In this part, we'll load up a CV and populate its disk cache with some snapshots. We'll use Python's `slice` explicitly; the more famliar colon notation (e.g., `some_list[:5]`, `some_list[5:]`) is just a shorthand for the `slice`.

```py
def save_partial_cv(storage, cv, snapshots_slice):
    """Do the main work of saving a block of CV results to disk"""
    cv = cv.with_diskcache(allow_incomplete=True)
    cv(storage.snapshots[snapshots_slice])
    
    # get a mapping of saved snapshot index to CV value
    cache = dict(cv._cache_dict.cache)
    idx_to_cv_value = {storage.snapshots.idx(s): val for s, val in cache.items()}

    # gets the label "cv{num}" for this cv
    store_name = cv._cache_dict.passing_chain[1].value_store.name

    nc_idx_var = storage.vars[f"{store_name}_index"]
    nc_val_var = storage.vars[f"{store_name}_value"]

    existing = len(nc_idx_var)
    nc_idx_var.variable[existing::] = list(idx_to_cv_value.keys())
    nc_val_var.variable[existing::] = list(idx_to_cv_value.values())

    storage.sync()

# this is the part that the script that will run for each section will do
import openpathsampling as paths
st3 = paths.Storage("foo.nc")
psi = st3.cvs['psi']

save_partial_cv(st3, psi, slice(0, 3))  # save st2.snapshots[0:3]

# Just to make like we did another block, let's use save_partial again.
# In practice, you'll probably run each slice in a separate script.
save_partial_cv(st3, psi, slice(6, None))  # save st2.snapshots[6:]
```

As a hack to prove it worked (for this toy demo), you can change the `cv_callable` for the CV (e.g., so that all snapshots return 0.0), and call `cv(storage.snapshots)` to show that we're returning the results from disk, not from evaluating the CV function.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the story here. It works great for this case (doing all the snaphshots). But in the case if want to do in two steps (i.e snapshots[:5] and after the last 5. That is why I try to use allow_incomplete. I am editing my question.

Comment: updated to handle the `allow_incomplete` case. It is a bit hacky, but seems to work -- hope this helps!

Comment: Thank but for me it still doesn't work (well, values of the CV is saved to the .nc file and is not recalculated but they are inccorect)